# Get a 500 error. But the directory is created

Tags: google-drive-api

Problem with response from google drive api. I send a request to create a directory but I get a 500 error. But the directory is created. Please somebody help me...

My request is:

```
/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=name,id,mimeType,parents,size,webContentLink,webViewLink,iconLink,thumbnailLink,createdTime,modifiedTime
```

headlines:

```
Authorization = Bearer + Token
Content-Type = Multipart/Related; boundary
Content-Length = 316
```

in response i should get the created directory id but i get unknown error and code 500. But the directory is created...